# Page is not supported by Windows Unviersal. MvvmBindingPack

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mvvm, uwp

When you add a MVVMBindingPack by Alexander Paskhin by nuget to a WIN 10 Solution (minimum RS1) (https://mvvmbindingpack.codeplex.com/) 
You will have a troubles like

"Page is not supported .. bla bla bla " and you wont be able to use designer, but you can compile.

[image]

Do anyone know how to resolve it?

How to reproduce:

1. Create UWP project.
2. Build it, no problem
3. Add MvvmBindingPack by Alexander Paskhin from nuget
4. Build it and check at MainPage.xaml erros

Also by this pack is created other error

`1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(2007,5): warning APPX1707: No implementation file was provided for the .winmd file 'C:\Users\Dell\.nuget\packages\MvvmBindingPack\1.8.5.1\lib\.NETCore50\Windows.winmd'. To generate registration information in the app manifest, specify the 'Implementation' metadata on the .winmd reference item in the project file.`

Comment: The universal examples of  `mvvmBindingPack` also had the same issue. You may try to ask author directly Alexander Paskhin (paskhin@hotmail.co.uk). But it didn't break  successful running.

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT I wanted to do this, but firstly I wanted to ask here. So, asking author left.